# Why do I get an Internal Dartium Exception when using custom elements?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am seeing this error in my console:

```
Exception: InvalidStateError: Internal Dartium Exception
  PolymerDeclaration.registerType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:241:22)
  PolymerDeclaration.register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:175:17)
  PolymerDeclaration._register (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:114:13)
  PolymerDeclaration.registerWhenReady (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:109:14)
  _notifyType (package:polymer/src/declaration.dart:514:49)
  Polymer.register (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:64:16)
  _loadLibrary (package:polymer/src/loader.dart:177:25)
```

I have code like this:

```
@CustomTag('person-tag')
class PersonTag extends PolymerElement {
```

And my HTML is like this:

```
<polymer-element name="person-tag" extends="li">
```

Why am I getting this `Internal Dartium Exception` error from `registerType` ?

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing this error because your HTML says `extends="li"` but the Dart code only extends `PolymerElement`.

If you use an `extends` attribute in your `polymer-element`, then your Dart class must also extend the same kind of element.

To fix the problem in the question, change the Dart class:

```
@CustomTag('person-tag')
class PersonTag extends LIElement with Polymer, Observable {
```

Now `PersonTag` really does extend `<li>`.