# Breaking on exception: Unsupported operation: Class must provide extendsTag if base native class is not HTMLElement

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

When I try to extend certain Element with Polymer like below, following error message emerges.

```
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends CanvasElement with Polymer {
  // something
}

Breaking on exception: Unsupported operation: Class must provide extendsTag if base native class is not HTMLElement
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you extend certain Element with Polymer in Dart code, you also have to add 'extends' attribute to polymer-element like below, or you get the Breaking on exception message.

```
<polymer-element name="click-counter" extends="canvas" attributes="count">
```

See also [Why do I get an Internal Dartium Exception when using custom elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556711/why-do-i-get-an-internal-dartium-exception-when-using-custom-elements/19556712)